# Speed up plot() function for large dataset

Tags: r, plot

I am using `plot()` for over 1 mln data points and it turns out to be very slow.

Is there any way to improve the speed including programming and hardware solutions (more RAM, graphic card...)?

Where are data for plot stored?

Comment: Summarise the data and plot the summary instead.

Comment: i need to plot and observe the data intuitively

Comment: Can you give more information about which plotting functions you are using? It makes a big difference whether you are using base graphics, lattice or ggplot.

Comment: This question needs a lot more context to be answered usefully; what are you hoping to see when you plot 1 million+ data points? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806404/plotting-huge-data-files-in-r is related.

Comment: What abt chart_Series and plot using base graphics?

Comment: If there is a way to speed up the following I would be interested in it: a<-rnorm(1E7,1,1); b<-rnorm(1E7,1,1); system.time(plot(a,b))

Comment: Sample the data and plot the sample instead.

Comment: Or you could sample the data down a bit and run several iterations and see what's going on.

Answer (score 27):

(This question is closely related to [Scatterplot with too many points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714677/scatterplot-with-too-many-points/16122003#16122003), although that question focuses on the difficulty of seeing anything in the big scatterplot rather than on performance issues ...)

A hexbin plot actually shows you something (unlike the scatterplot @Roland proposes in the comments, which is likely to just be a giant, slow, blob) and takes about 3.5 seconds on my machine for your example:

```
set.seed(101)
a<-rnorm(1E7,1,1)
b<-rnorm(1E7,1,1)
library(hexbin)
system.time(plot(hexbin(a,b)))  ## 0.5 seconds, modern laptop
```

[image]

Another, slightly slower alternative is the base-R `smoothScatter` function: it plots a smooth density plus as many extreme points as requested (1000 in this case).

```
system.time(smoothScatter(a,b,cex=4,nr=1000))  ## 3.3 seconds
```

[image]

Comment: This is an important point:  nobody can absorb the meaning of millions, or even thousands of points (except maybe some of those "artistic" fractal charts :-) ), so find a way to cluster or otherwise reduce the magnitude of items to plot.

Comment: I did not know this package and your answer is helpful to a specific problem of presenting results in a paper I am preparing. +1 for that. However, the question remains: What is limiting while plotting? Is it just CPU power or something else?

Comment: The device drivers do not handle such a large plotting task very well. There is a lot of overhead to plotting a single point. It's not just two numbers but requires consideration of the coloring and transparency capabilities. It's not just R. PDF viewers will bog down considerably when given an image with millions of dots to render.

Comment: You can actually save a lot of time by using `pch="."`; you may be able to speed things up by (e.g.) plotting straight to PNG rather than screen or PDF (that will also make the size of your final plot much smaller)

Answer (score 19):

an easy and fast way is to set `pch='.'` . The performance is shown below

```
x=rnorm(10^6)
> system.time(plot(x))
  user  system elapsed 
  2.87   15.32   18.74 
> system.time(plot(x,pch=20))
  user  system elapsed 
  3.59   22.20   26.16 
> system.time(plot(x,pch='.'))
  user  system elapsed 
  1.78    2.26    4.06
```

Answer (score 2):

have you looked at the tabplot package. it is designed specifically for large data 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tabplot/ I use that its faster than using hexbin (or even the default sunflower plots for overplotting)

also i think Hadley wrote something on DS 's blog  modifying ggplot for big data at http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2011/10/ggplot2-for-big-data.html

"""I'm currently with working another student, Yue Hu, to turn our research into a robust R package.""" October 21, 2011

Maybe we can ask Hadley if the updated ggplot3 is ready

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked at a time when the `reticulate` package to run Python commands from R didn't yet exist.

It's now possible to call the highly efficient [`matplotlib` Python library](https://matplotlib.org/) to plot a large dataset.

`matplotlib` setup in R is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089600/13513328).

Plotting 1 Million points with `matplotlib` takes around 1.5 seconds:

```r
library(reticulate)
library(png)

mpl <- import("matplotlib")
mpl$use("Agg") # Stable non interactive back-end
plt <- import("matplotlib.pyplot")
mpl$rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 0 # Disable error check on too many points

# generate points cloud
a <-rnorm(1E6,1,1)
b <-rnorm(1E6,1,1)

system.time({
  plt$figure()
  plt$plot(a,b,'.',markersize=1)
  # Save figure
  f <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
  plt$savefig(f)
  # Close figure
  plt$close(plt$gcf())
  # Show image
  img <- readPNG(f)
  grid::grid.raster(img)
  # Close temporary file
  unlink(f)
})
```

[image]

```
#>        User      System       Total 
#>        1.29        0.15        1.49
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been mentioned here, but plotting to a high-resolution raster image is another reasonable choice (if you really want to plot a giant blob :-) ). It will be very slow to create, but the resulting image will be a reasonable size, and will open quickly. Because PNGs [compress the file based on similarity of neighboring pixels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Compression), the exterior (all-white) and interior (all-black) of the blob don't take any more storage space as the resolution gets larger - all you're doing is rendering the edge of the blob in more detail.

```
set.seed(101)
a<-rnorm(1E7,1,1)
b<-rnorm(1E7,1,1)
png("blob.png",width=1000,height=1000)
system.time(plot(a,b)) ## 170 seconds on an old Macbook Pro
dev.off()
```

The resulting image file is 123K, and could be made much higher-resolution with a small increase in rendering size (both in creating and opening the file) and file size.

[image]