# Scatterplot with Color Gradient from the Mean

Tags: r, plot, color-gradient

I have a data frame "DF" of 2020 observations and 79066 variables. The first column is the year spanning continuously from 1 to 2020, the other columns (variables) are numbers.

For reproducibility, I created I fake data frame with 20 years from 2000 to 2020, and only 100 variables. E.g.:

```
set.seed(123)

i <- 100

DF <- data.frame(year=c(2000:2020), 
                 setNames(
                   as.data.frame(lapply(1:i, function(k) c(rnorm(21)))), 
                   paste("Var_", 1:i, sep = "")))
```

I then created a Mean by row

```
DF$Aver <- apply(DF[, 2:101], 1, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I then plotted the average as a line and added the points

```
plot(DF$year, DF$Aver, type="l", col=1, cex=0.5, las=1, xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(-4, 4)) 
for (i in 2:101) {
  points(DF$year, DF[, i], pch=20, cex=1, col='gray')
}
```

However, what I would like to have is a scatterplot where the points close to the mean are dark grey and the grey colour goes shading (light grey) towards the tail values.

Answer (score 0):

You could `normalize` the variable in iteration and use it as *alpha* value in the `rgb(red, gree, blue, alpha)` function, where values are between [0, 1]. Since smallest values get zero alpha, we simply make `points` a second time with a very light gray.

```
normalize <- function(x, na.rm=FALSE) {
  na <- is.na(x)
  x[na] <- min(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  num <- x - min(x)
  denom <- max(x) - min(x)
  return(replace(num/denom, na, NA_real_))
}

plot(DF$year, DF$Aver, type="l", col=1, cex=0.5, las=1, xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(-4, 4)) 
for (i in 2:101) {
  # points(DF$year, DF[, i], pch=20, cex=1, col=rgb(.8, .8, .8, 1 - normalize(abs(DF[, i]))))
  points(DF$year, DF[, i], pch=20, cex=1, col=rgb(.8, .8, .8, 1 - {nz <- normalize(abs(DF[, i])); replace(nz, is.na(nz), 0)}))
  points(DF$year, DF[, i], pch=20, cex=1, col=rgb(.1, .1, .1, .05))
  # points(DF$year, DF[, i], pch=20, cex=1, col='gray')
}
```

[image]

### Update

It is not feasible to plot a huge number of points like 159,713,320 in your case. The human eye cannot resolve this, and a nasty surprise could be waiting for us in the copy store.

A common way of solving the issue is to use a smaller random `sample` `s` of the data with a fraction of the columns in the `size=` argument. (No need to care for integers, `sample` will round reals.) It will represent your data adequately.

```
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
s <- sample(2:ncol(DF_huge), size=(ncol(DF_huge) - 1)*.0005)  ## see data below
```

We might initialize an empty `plot` using `type=`n`, since the line will be overlaid from the` points` anyway.

Next, in the `for` loop for the `points` we iterate exactly over this subset `s`. Here with that many points, we could simplify to a single color `'#RRGGBBaa'` defined in hexadecimal format 1-F, where R=red, G=green, B=blue and a=alpha (opacity). I commented on the approach from above, but you might want to try both.

Finally, using `lines` we draw the average line as the top layer, where we may use the whole dataset.

```
plot(DF_huge$year, DF_huge$Aver, type="n", las=1, xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(-4, 4)) 
for (i in s) {
  v <- .5
  # points(DF_huge$year, DF_huge[, i], pch='.', cex=3,
  #        col=rgb(v, v, v, 1 - {nz <- normalize(abs(DF_huge[, i])); replace(nz, is.na(nz), 0)}))
  points(DF_huge$year, DF_huge[, i], pch='.', cex=3, col="#88888833")
}
lines(DF_huge$year, DF_huge$Aver, type="l", col=1, cex=0.5, las=1, xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(-4, 4))
```

[image]

**See also** these older questions dealing with plotting of large data: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7714677/6574038), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10945707/6574038), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15901834/6574038).

---

*Data:*

```
n <- 2020
m <- 79066
set.seed(42)
Var <- replicate(m, rnorm(n))
Var[sample(seq_along(Var), 2000)] <- NA_real_  ## produce 2000 random missings
DF_huge <- data.frame(year=seq_len(n), Var=Var)

DF_huge$Aver <- rowMeans(DF_huge[-1], na.rm=TRUE)  ## much faster than `apply(., mean)`!
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however I got this error message because I have NA values

`Error in rgb(red = 0.8, green = 0.8, blue = 0.8, alpha = 1 - normalize(abs(DF[,  : 
  alpha level NA, not in [0,1]`

Comment: @AlmaPiermattei I see, I enhanced `normalize()` a little, see if it works now.

Comment: Thank you, I used your modified `normalize()` function but unfortunately, I got the same error message

Comment: @AlmaPiermattei Ok, I implemented a hack, that `replace`s NAs with 0 (i.e. no alpha thus blank in this case which makes sense), please review!

Comment: Thank you, I ran the script for the 2020 rows and 79066 columns, and I got this error: `Error in dev.off() : internal compression error -5 in PDF_endpage`.
Additionally, I'm not so sure it works with all values. I ran the script for 1000 columns and I don't see the gradient

Comment: @AlmaPiermattei Great, so the code works. Do I understand you right and you are attempting to plot 2020*79,066=159,713,320 points? This is quite a load, and your error might be related to that.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to plot 159,713,320 points but it doesn't work

Comment: @AlmaPiermattei You could try `png` but I'm sure, the number is not feasible for plotting—technically, and also the human eye wouldn't be able to resolve it anyway. Draw an appropriate random sample, see updated answer.