# plot large data set in R with less time

Tags: r, matrix, plot, ggplot2, bigdata

I have two huge datasets, not very huge, two double matrix of 5000*5000.
  Say the matrix names are A and B,

I tried

```
plot(as.vector(A),as.vector(B))
```

But it seems like taking forever... Are there any suggested packages for plotting such large data set ?

basically, I am plotting x=(2.5E+07), y=(2.5E+07), quite huge but reasonable size data sets.

Comment: This sort of thing has been discussed previously, see: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7348/more-efficient-plot-functions-in-r-when-millions-of-points-are-present and http://www.biostars.org/p/47288/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945707/speed-up-plot-function-for-large-dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create a scatter plot, then the "hexbin" package may provide a better plot because a plot with 25M points is hard to understand.  If you reallynwant to use "plot", then try the parameter

pch="."