# plotting pairwise scatter plot for high throughput data

Tags: r, visualization, scatter-plot

I have 13 variables that each of them has up to 1000000 elements. I want to draw a pairwise scatterplot for them but I couldn't do that because the size of my data was large. Any idea to do such thing?
I have tried this:

```
pairs(data.mat)
graphics.off()

library(GGally)
ggpairs(data.mat, colour='Species', alpha=0.4)
```

and it couldn't do that and came out from R software.

Comment: Could you share, what you have tried? And what is the error you face?

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945707/speed-up-plot-function-for-large-dataset?

Comment: @ًًQaswed yes but it couldn't help me

Answer (score 1):

1) Use a subset of your dataset. You're not going to make meaningful conclusions from 1 million points that you cannot from many fewer.

2) Use pch=".", it speeds things up a surprising amount.

3) Consider plotting the joint distributions rather than the individual points.