# Efficient rendering of data points from large data plot in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, large-data

## Goal

Implement a Shiny app to efficiently visualize and adjust uploaded data sets. Each set may contain 100000 to 200000 rows. After data adjustments are done, the adjusted data can be downloaded. In steps:

1. Data upload
2. Data selection and visualization
3. Data (point) removal
4. Download option

## Issue

While the app works in principal, data visualization and removal take too much time.

## Code

#### Sample data

Some sample data is generated. The data can be uploaded onto the shiny app. The sample data distribution is not similar to my actual data. The actual data contains clearly identifiable outliers and looks like a spectra with peaks.

```
a = sample(1:1e12, 1e5, replace=TRUE)
b = sample(1:1e12, 1e5, replace=TRUE)
dummy1 = data.frame(Frequency = a, Amplitude = a)
dummy2 = data.frame(Frequency = b, Amplitude = b)
dummy3 = data.frame(Frequency = a, Amplitude = b)
# Sample data
write.csv(dummy1,'dummy1.csv')
write.csv(dummy2,'dummy2.csv')
write.csv(dummy3,'dummy2.csv')
```

#### Shiny app

The app takes the uploaded data and plots it. (Sample dummy data can be uploaded onto the app.) Section of data points can be removed and the new data can be downloaded.

```
# Packages
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
# UI
ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(selectInput("selection", "Set Selection:", choices = '', selected = '', multiple = TRUE)),
    fluidRow(plotOutput(outputId = "plot", brush = "plot_brush_"), 
             downloadButton('download',"Download the data"))
)

# Server
server = function(session, input, output){
    # Pop up for data upload
    query_modal = modalDialog(title = "Upload Spectrum",
                              fileInput("file", 
                              "file",
                              multiple = TRUE,
                              accept = c(".csv")),
                              easyClose = FALSE)
    showModal(query_modal)

    ## Upload
    mt1 = reactive({
       req(input$file)
       cs = list()
       for(nr in 1:length(input$file[ , 1])){
          c = read.csv(input$file[[nr, 'datapath']])
          cs[[nr]] = data.table(Frequency = as.numeric(c[[1]]), 
                                Amplitude = as.numeric(c[[2]]), 
                                Indicator = as.factor(nr))}
        c = do.call(rbind, cs)
        c = reactiveValues(data = c)
        return(c)})

    ## Input selection
    observeEvent(
      mt1(),
      updateSelectInput(
        session, 
        "selection", 
        "Set Selection:", 
        choices = levels(mt1()$data$Indicator), 
        selected = 'Entire'))
    
    ## Plot
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      mt = mt1()$data
      mt = mt[mt$Indicator %in% input$selection,]
      p = ggplot(mt, aes(Frequency, Amplitude, color = Indicator)) 
      p + geom_point(show.legend = TRUE)})
    
    ## Download
    output$download = downloadHandler(
      filename = function(){paste(gsub('.{1}$', '', input$file$name[1]), 'manipulated', '.csv', sep= '')}, 
      content = function(fname){
        mt = mt1()$data
        mt = mt[, .SD, .SDcols= c('Frequency', 
                                  'Amplitude', 
                                  'Indicator')]
        write.csv(mt, fname, row.names = FALSE)})
    
    ## Adjust
    observe({
      d = mt$data
      keep = mt$data[!Indicator %in% input$selection]
      df = brushedPoints(d, brush = input$plot_brush_, allRows = TRUE) 
      df = df[selected_ == FALSE]
      df$selected_ = NULL
      mt$data = rbind(keep , df[Indicator %in% input$selection,  ])})
}

# Run app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: All the code related to shiny is irrelevant. You have a pure plotting/ggplot2 issue. Plotting many points is slow. You need to redesign the plots and work on more effective data visualization. It is never sensible to plot 1e5 points. You will have dramatic over-plotting. If you don't want to work on more effective visualization, this answer of mine could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16668596/1412059

Comment: " I'd currently change the data itself" What is the issue with that if *the plot* is still exactly the same? It's impossible to distinguish 1e5 points in a plot. Also, you should look at other options (like a hexbin plot).

Comment: @Roland, I agree it being a plotting issue. However, plotting of the data points is necessary as the plot serves as a visualization tool to know what data points to remove but also as a data manipulation tool for data removal. I like your approximation approach. I'd have to have knowledge on the data size and precision which is no prob. I don't get why R's ggplot or base plot take so much more time than Python's matplotlib. I guess, besides approximations it'd be ideal to have the same selection layer functionality operating on the raw data on top of a plot with approximated and reduced data.

Comment: @Roland, I confirm that 1e5 points is not a big deal for matplotlib as well as for Matlab, see my answer.

Comment: possibly useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945707/speed-up-plot-function-for-large-dataset/10946907#10946907

Answer (score 2):

You could use `matplotlib` Python drawing library inside R and Shiny with the `reticulate` package :

1. Set up the package and the libraries :

```
install.packages('reticulate')

# Install python environment
reticulate::install_miniconda() 
# if Python is already installed, you can specify the path with use_python(path)

# Install matplotlib library
reticulate::py_install('matplotlib')
```

2. test installation :

```
library(reticulate)
mpl <- import("matplotlib")
mpl$use("Agg") # Stable non interactive backend
mpl$rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 0 # Disable error check on too many points

plt <- import("matplotlib.pyplot")
np <- import("numpy")

# generate lines cloud
xx = np$random$randn(100000L)
yy = np$random$randn(100000L)

plt$figure()
plt$plot(xx,yy)
plt$savefig('test.png')
plt$close(plt$gcf())
```

test.png :

[image]

3. Use `matplotlib` in Shiny, drawing duration below 2 seconds for 1e5 segments :

```
# Packages
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
# UI
ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(selectInput("selection", "Set Selection:", choices = '', selected = '', multiple = TRUE)),
  fluidRow(imageOutput(outputId = "image"), 
           downloadButton('download',"Download the data"))
)

# Server
server = function(session, input, output){
  
  # Setup Python objects
  mpl <- reticulate::import("matplotlib")
  plt <- reticulate::import("matplotlib.pyplot")
  mpl$use("Agg") 
  mpl$rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 0
  
  
  # Pop up for data upload
  query_modal = modalDialog(title = "Upload Spectrum",
                            fileInput("file", 
                                      "file",
                                      multiple = TRUE,
                                      accept = c(".csv")),
                            easyClose = FALSE)
  showModal(query_modal)
  
  ## Upload
  mt1 = reactive({
    req(input$file)
    cs = list()
    for(nr in 1:length(input$file[ , 1])){
      c = read.csv(input$file[[nr, 'datapath']])
      cs[[nr]] = data.table(Frequency = as.numeric(c[[1]]), 
                            Amplitude = as.numeric(c[[2]]), 
                            Indicator = as.factor(nr))}
    c = do.call(rbind, cs)
    c = reactiveValues(data = c)
    return(c)})
  
  ## Input selection
  observeEvent(
    mt1(),
    updateSelectInput(
      session, 
      "selection", 
      "Set Selection:", 
      choices = levels(mt1()$data$Indicator), 
      selected = 'Entire'))
  
  ## Render matplotlib image
  output$image <- renderImage({
    # Read myImage's width and height. These are reactive values, so this
    # expression will re-run whenever they change.
    width  <- session$clientData$output_image_width
    height <- session$clientData$output_image_height
    
    # For high-res displays, this will be greater than 1
    pixelratio <- session$clientData$pixelratio
    
    # A temp file to save the output.
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
    
    # Generate the image file
    mt = mt1()$data
    mt = mt[mt$Indicator %in% input$selection,]
    xx = mt$Frequency
    yy = mt$Amplitude
    
    plt$figure()
    plt$plot(xx,yy)
    plt$savefig(outfile)
    plt$close(plt$gcf())
    
    # Return a list containing the filename
    list(src = outfile,
         width = width,
         height = height,
         alt = "This is alternate text")
  }, deleteFile = TRUE)
  
  ## Download
  output$download = downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){paste(gsub('.{1}$', '', input$file$name[1]), 'manipulated', '.csv', sep= '')}, 
    content = function(fname){
      mt = mt1()$data
      mt = mt[, .SD, .SDcols= c('Frequency', 
                                'Amplitude', 
                                'Indicator')]
      write.csv(mt, fname, row.names = FALSE)})
  
  ## Adjust
  observe({
    mt = mt1()
    df = brushedPoints(mt$data, brush = input$plot_brush_, allRows = TRUE) 
    mt$data = df[df$selected_ == FALSE,  ]})
}

# Run app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]
You'll need to handle color manually, because `matplotlib` isn't `ggplot2`

Comment: When I run this Shiny app, manual data point removal via data selection is not possible. Despite that, the integration of matplotlib via reticulate is handy.