# R crashed when using Geom_Point for large data frame

Tags: r

**Background:** I have a large data frame `data_2014`, containing ~ 1,000,000 rows like this

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
date_time = "4/1/2014 0:11:00",
Lat = 40.7690,
Lon = -73.9549,
Base = "B02512"
)
```

**Problem:** I want to create a plot like this [image]

This is what I've attempted to do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(scales)

    min_lat <- 40.5774
    max_lat <- 40.9176
    min_long <- -74.15
    max_long <- -73.7004
    
    ggplot(data_2014, aes(Lon, Lat)) + 
      geom_point(size = 1, color = "chocolate") + 
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(min_long, max_long)) + 
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min_lat, max_lat)) +
      theme_map() + 
      ggtitle("NYC Map Based on Uber Rides Data (April-September 2014)")
```

However, when I ran this code, Rstudio crashed. I'm not particularly sure how to fix or improve this. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: possibly useful information in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945707/speed-up-plot-function-for-large-dataset

Comment: What operating system are you using and how much RAM is installed on the machine? I am able to produce the chart on a MacBook Pro 15 with 16Gb of RAM, using R 4.0.3 and the latest versions of packages listed in your question. The plot took about 2 minutes to run, and another 4 minutes to render in the RStudio graphics viewer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A million points is a lot for ggplot2, but do-able if your computer is good enough.  Yours may or may not be. Short of getting a bigger computer here's what you should do.

1. This is spatial data, so use the `sf` package.

```
library(sf)
data_2014 <- st_as_sf(data_2014, coords = c('Lon', 'Lat')) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)
```

2. If you're only plotting the points, get rid of the columns of data you don't need.  I'm guessing they might include trip distance, time, borough, etc. Use `dplyr`'s `select`, or whatever other method you're familiar with.
3. Try plotting some of the data, and then a little more.  See where your computer slows down & stop there.  You can plot the data from row 1:n, or sample x number of rows.

```
# try starting with 100,000 and go up from there.
n <- 100000
ggplot(data_2014[1:n,]) +
 geom_sf()

# Alternatively sample a fraction of the data.
# Start with ~10% and go up until R crashes again.
data_2015 %>% 
  sample_frac(.1) %>%
ggplot() + 
 geom_sf()
```